# Prove that a given ideal is not maximal in $\mathbb C[x,y,z]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, ideals

I'm trying to prove this ideal:

> $$(x^2+y^2+z^2+x+y+z,\ x^5+y^5+z^5+2(x+y+z),\ x^7+y^7+z^7+3(x+y+z))\subset
>  \mathbb C[x,y,z]$$

can't be maximal.

In order to do so, I'm using the Nullstellensatz theorem and showing this ideal is not of this form: $(x-a_1,y-a_2,z-a_3)$, where $a_i\in \mathbb C$.

The problem I don't how to do this.

Comment: What's $3(x,y,z)$? Is it a typo for $3(x+y+z)$?

Comment: Note : Even in English, this theorem is usually called with its German name, the Nullstellensatz. (Pronounce it "Nullchtellenzats" with an english pronounciation, that's as close you'll get...)

Comment: Let's call your ideal $I$.  As a first step, can you specifically identify a maximal ideal that contains $I$?

Comment: @egreg I'm sorry, I'm going to edit it

Comment: @PatrickDaSilva thanks for the remark!

Comment: @JohnM $(x,y,z)$?

Comment: @user85493 : Precisely. I think that the fact that all your generators are symmetric polynomials might help you, but I'm not sure.

Comment: So now can you show strict containment $(x,y,z) \supsetneq I$?  So for example, if you could somehow prove that $x \notin I$?

Comment: @JohnM intuitively it seems pretty obvious, because of the powers of the generators of this ideal, but I don't know how to formalize it.

Comment: Do you know how to compute Gröbner bases? That's the brute force approach, but it will work for sure

Comment: @JohnM because of the date it was asked I presume the author is one of the students who are taking the same course I'm taking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $J=(x,y,z)$. We have $I+(x^2,y^2,z^2)=(x+y+z,x^2,y^2,z^2)\subsetneq J$ and then $I$ is not maximal because clearly $I\subseteq J$.

Comment: Why we don't have $(x+y+z,x^2,y^2,z^2)=J$?

Comment: For example, the elements of that ideal which are homogeneous of degree $1$ together with zero form a $1$-dimensional vector space. On the othe thand, the elements of $J$ which are homogeneous and of degreee $1$, together with zero, for a $3$-dimensional vector space.

Answer (score 1):

To show your ideal is not maximal, I'll show that the set of common zeros of your ideal contains more than one point. Taking advantage of the symmetry of your ideal, we will look for solutions that even satisfy the extra condition $x+y+z=0.$ Then (using [Newton's Identities](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_identities#Expressing_power_sums_in_terms_of_elementary_symmetric_polynomials) and remember $e_1=x+y+z=0$) the first equation is $$x^2+y^2+z^2+x+y+z = p_2 + e_1 = p_2 = e_1^2 - 2e_2.$$

The next one is  $$ x^5+y^5+z^5 + 2(x+y+z) = p_5 + 2e_1 = -5e_3e_2 $$ and the third is

$$ x^7+y^7+z^7 + 3(x+y+z) = p_7 + 3e_1 = c e_3 e_2^2$$ where $c$ is a non-zero constant.

This system is satisfied if we further impose $e_2=0.$ Hence, any common solutions of $e_1=x+y+z=0$ and $e_2 = xy+yz+xz=0$ are in the set of common zeros of your ideal. It is easy to find solutions to this that aren't the trivial $(0,0,0)$ solution. For example, pick $x=1,$ so $y+z=-1$ and $y+yz+z =0,$ which easily solves for $y= \dfrac{-1}{2} - i \dfrac{\sqrt{3}}{2} \ , \ z = \dfrac{-1}{2} + i \dfrac{\sqrt{3}}{2}.$

Comment: Interesting approach.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this works?

For any $f(x,y,z) \in \mathbb{C}[x,y,z]$, it seems clear that
$$f(x,y,z)(x+y+z) \not\equiv x (\bmod \langle x^2,y^2,z^2 \rangle).$$
Therefore,
$$x \notin \langle x^2,y^2,z^2,x+y+z \rangle.$$

So we have
$$\langle x,y,z \rangle \supsetneq \langle x^2, y^2, z^2, x+y+z \rangle \supseteq I,$$
where $I$ is the ideal given by the problem statement.